# persistence.xml issue

Tags: java, xml, entity, persistence

i'm started with java EE and i don't understand at all where is my probleme..
i need help please :) 
I've a probleme with my persistence.xml

here my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="QuickStarter-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        </provider>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DIALECT" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/QuickStarter" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and here my error

i don't understand the probleme i'm trying to connect with my DB but no way.. 
if someone have an idea it's welcome :) thanks

```
24 nov. 2013 00:04:33 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'value' must appear on element 'property'.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.quickStarter.util.PersistenceManager.getEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceManager.java:14)
    at com.quickStarter.dao.DaoFactory.getUserDao(DaoFactory.java:32)
    at com.quickStarter.servlet.inscriptionUser.init(inscriptionUser.java:22)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
24 nov. 2013 00:04:33 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'allocation pour la servlet com.quickStarter.servlet.inscriptionUser
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'value' must appear on element 'property'.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.quickStarter.util.PersistenceManager.getEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceManager.java:14)
    at com.quickStarter.dao.DaoFactory.getUserDao(DaoFactory.java:32)
    at com.quickStarter.servlet.inscriptionUser.init(inscriptionUser.java:22)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: `@OneToOne` but you have a `List`?

Comment: i don't think so, where i put my list ? i'm a beginner at java maybe i've some missed parts

Comment: Your `projects` field is of type `List` but it is annotated with `@OneToOne`. Why do you think that makes sense?

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand.. can you explain me please i don't understand the relation btw my entity and my probleme..

Comment: The javadoc for `OneToOne` states: `Specifies a single-valued association to another entity that has one-to-one multiplicity.` A `List` implies a multi-valued association. Don`t use them together.

Comment: ok so what i've to do, because i'm a really beginner. do you have some link where i can understand more please

Comment: Start with the javadoc and the official JPA documentation.

Comment: ok so my problem come to my entity implementation ?

Comment: Yes, `OneToOne` means one entity is related to one entity, not to a `List` of entities.

Comment: ok ok i'm gonna to read the javadoc and the jpa documentation, i'm gonna to try and i come after, thanks very much for your faster help :)